# When I use custom domain, Heroku error: There's nothing here, yet

Tags: heroku, deployment

I have an app on Heroku hosting and I'm able to reach it from app.herokuapp.com.
I bought a domain from **name.com** and added it to custom domain at heroku (www.mydomain.com).
On name.com I've configured ANAME dns type:
**Host**: www.mydomain.com
**Answer**: app.herokudns.com  (provided by heroku).  I read lot of problems related to this but any solution worked for me.  What can  i do? is my dns configuration ok?

Comment: You need to set CNAME www to the DNS target in Heroku. The DNS target ends with "herokudns.com", and in my app it's *not* app.herokudns.com it's another name in place of "app".

Comment: Thanks, im trying that. Should I keep the ANAME row?

Comment: I have a similar setup to you and don't have any ANAME set so I don't believe you need it.

Comment: It's working now. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome! I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set CNAME www to the DNS target in Heroku. The DNS target ends with "herokudns.com", and at least in my app it's not app.herokudns.com it's a bunch of characters and numbers in place of "app".

Comment: As comment I changed www to *.  Thank you for your help